# How to extract rows where a series of objects are either of the two columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df. The number of observations run upto hundreds of millions. I have a series that consists of a large number (around 15 million) of addresses. I want to extract rows if either from or to address can be found in the series.

```
    from_address to_address value   block_timestamp
0   0xcf1cc6s   0x272d9fa   1.01485 2018-06-03 09:13:22+00:00
1   0xbfb92c3   0x24d941b   3.097   2018-06-03 09:13:22+00:00
2   0x58076fd   0x5b89cb8   1.9089  2018-06-03 09:13:22+00:00
3   0x0000000   0xbe80455   7.71195 2018-06-03 09:13:22+00:00
4   0x0000000   0x334f5b0   7.71133 2018-06-03 09:13:22+00:00
5   0x0000000   0x9b54db8   1e+21   2018-06-03 09:13:22+00:00
6   0x84b06bd   0x2a0c0db   2.185   2018-06-03 10:55:46+00:00
7   0x59a5202   0x3122da2   1633277 2018-06-03 10:55:46+00:00
8   0x59a520a   0x02d9112   1.606   2018-06-03 10:55:46+00:00
9   0x5e57d43   0xd64d144   1.472   2018-06-03 01:02:14+00:00
```

My code:

```
series= list['address'].str.lower()

df_extracted = df[df['from_address'].isin(series) 
                                            | df['to_address'].isin(series)]
```

But somehow, when I look at the original df and look at all the rows which contains a specific address, i get 136 rows, whereas if i do the same with df_extracted, i only get 12. So when i am extracting rows using the above code, I am doing something wrong. Does anyone have any clue what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It is the same :/ it is dropping too many observations i need... i can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Is there other way to do what I am meant to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```py
addresses = ['0x0000000', '0x2a0c0db']
df.query('from_address in @addresses or to_address in @addresses')
```

It's supposed to work the same way as your code so maybe check your dataframe just before you apply this operation.

The result I'm getting:

```py
        from_add     to_add    value            block_timestamp
index                                                           
3      0x0000000  0xbe80455  7.71195  2018-06-03 09:13:22+00:00
4      0x0000000  0x334f5b0  7.71133  2018-06-03 09:13:22+00:00
5      0x0000000  0x9b54db8    1e+21  2018-06-03 09:13:22+00:00
6      0x84b06bd  0x2a0c0db    2.185  2018-06-03 10:55:46+00:00
```

Comment: I get exactly the same result, but then again, it is dropping more observations than it should.. my list includes ~ 15 million addresses, no idea what is going on..:/

Comment: please share more code - what you do to search the original / filtered dataframes by address etc. the condition is fine, I bet the problem lies elsewhere

Comment: I added the update, with original (shorter df) my dfs are way to big to include here. but the logic is there